# Perturbation in 2D oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

2D oscillator

$H_0=\frac{P_x^2}{2m}+\frac{P_y^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\left(x^2+y^2\right)$

with perturbation

$H_1=h\omega \left(\frac{L_z^2}{h}-2\right)$

How to write the perturbation in terms of the creation-annihilation operators?
This is different and I don't know how to deal with $L_z^2$

Answer (score 3):

The angular momentum is classically given by:

$$ \mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r}\times \mathbf{p} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad L_i = \epsilon_{ijk}r_j p_k.$$
You quantisie it by replacing $x$ and $p$ by the quantum mechanical operators:
$$ \begin{align}r_i & = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} (a^\dagger_i + a_i) \qquad \mathrm{and} \qquad  p_i= \mathrm{i}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}} (a^\dagger_i - a_i) \end{align},  $$ where $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are the annihilation and creator operators (respectively), and $i$ is the dimension ($x$ or $y$).

Then,

$$ L_i = -\mathrm{i}\hbar\epsilon_{ijk} a^\dagger_j a_k$$

and hence:

$$ L_z = -\mathrm{i}\hbar\epsilon_{zjk} a^\dagger_j a_k = -\mathrm{i}\hbar(a_x^\dagger a_y - a^\dagger_ya_x). $$

After some algebra, I got:

$$L_z^2 = -\hbar^2 \left [  (a_x^\dagger)^2(a_y)^2 + (a_x)^2(a_y^\dagger)^2 -a_xa_x^{\dagger} - a_ya_y^\dagger  \right ]. $$

Answer (score 0):

This is a curious problem as it can be solved exactly since $L_z$ commutes with the unperturbed Hamiltonian and the eigenvalues of $L_z$ are already known.

Indeed, one can verify using the so-called Schwinger realization of angular momentum operators
\begin{align}
\hat L_z\mapsto\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\left(a_x^\dagger a_x-a^\dagger_y a_y\right)\, ,
\quad 
\hat L_+\mapsto \hat a^\dagger_x a_y\, ,\quad \hat L_-\mapsto \hat a^\dagger_ya_x
\end{align}
that states with $n=n_x+n_y$ are mapped to angular momentum states 
\begin{align}
\vert n_x n_y\rangle\mapsto \vert j,m\rangle
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
j=\textstyle\frac{1}{2}n\, ,\qquad m=\textstyle\frac{1}{2}(n_x-n_y)\, .
\end{align}
Thus, the eigenvalues of $L_z$ run from $n/2$ to $-n/2$ in steps of $1$, and we have
\begin{align}
L_z\vert {n_x,n_y}\rangle =\textstyle\frac{1}{2}(n_x-n_y)\vert n_x,n_y\rangle
\end{align}

Moreover, it is not clear how $L_z^2$ is a perturbation since it does not connect states with different total $n$ and all states with the same total $n$ are degenerate in energy.  Thus, one would have to use degenerate perturbation theory but the basis $\vert n_x,n_y\rangle$ already diagonalises the perturbation, so no work needs to be done.

Since the spectrum of $L_z^2$ is doubly degenerate (except for $m=0$), one could always take combination of the $\pm m$ eigenstates, i.e.
\begin{align}
\alpha \vert n_x,n_y\rangle +\beta \vert n_y,n_x\rangle
\end{align}
but there is no reason to choose these over the usual $\vert n_x,n_y\rangle$ basis, as least as the question is currently stated.